# Selenium on find_element

Tags: python, selenium

I tried with find_element_by() and I noticed that 3.5 Selenium version changed to find_element syntax but there are two ways: find_element(By.ID, "id-name") and find_element("id", "id-name") which one is the correct way? It worked the 2nd way but first one didn't. What do I have to consider to use one?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct

By.ID is literally an attribute with a string value of 'id'

BY.ID is better to use just in case they change this in the future, so you do not have to update your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the first option (at least that's what I understand from your question) you need to import `By`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

And then you can locate elements like:

```
element = browser.find_element(By.ID, "id-name")
```

It is however  advisable to always wait for elements to load, so you may also want to import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

And too try and locate elements like so:

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler")))
```

Selenium documentation can be found here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/